# Doctrine 2: Combine Select with Select from another table with identical structure

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

In my Symfony application in which I use Doctrine 2 I have two tables:
APPOINTMENTS and APPOINTMENTS_ARCHIVED.
Both tables have an identical (!) structure with identical fields!

My function in my AppointmentsRepository:

```
private function getAppointments()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $qb->leftJoin('a.instructor', 'i')
        ->leftJoin('i.contactdetails', 'c')
        ->join('a.area', 'ar');  

    return $qb;
}
```

This repository points to my table APPOINTMENTS.

How can I add a select of data in APPOINTMENTS_ARCHIVED to this query? My goal is that my query does not only consider data in my table APPOINTMENTS, but in addition data in my table with archived data APPOINTMENTS_ARCHIVED.

Comment: Do you have an entity for the "APPOINTMENTS_ARCHIVED" table?

Comment: @JannesBotis Yes. It is identical with Appointments.php.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `APPOINTMENTS_ARCHIVED` table is an archived version of the `APPOINTMENTS` table ?

This means that the archived table is not mapped to an entity, therefore impossible to get with [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)

Your best bet would be to to user [Native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can select multiple entities without them been related. In this case:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
$qb->addSelect('aa')
   ->from(AppointmentArchived::class, 'aa'); // ->join(AppointmentArchived::class, 'aa'); will also work
$qb->leftJoin('a.instructor', 'i')
    ->leftJoin('i.contactdetails', 'c')
    ->join('a.area', 'ar');  
$qb->leftJoin('aa.instructor', 'aai')
    ->leftJoin('aai.contactdetails', 'aac')
    ->join('aa.area', 'aar');
```

You have to join and select the relations separately in this case.